# HTTP Error 500.30: caused by dbContext.Database.Migrate()

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

dbContext.Database.Migrate() is causing HTTP error 500.30. Running the project with Visual Studio does not create any problem or error. Publishing it to my ASP.NET server causes the HTTP error. Anyone who knows how to solve this?

***program.cs***

```
using DataConnection.Areas.Identity;
using DataConnection.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, RevalidatingIdentityAuthenticationStateProvider<IdentityUser>>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();

var app = builder.Build();

// CAUSING HTTP ERROR 500.30:
using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
    dbContext.Database.Migrate();
}

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();
app.MapBlazorHub();
app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");

app.Run();
```

Comment: 500 could mean that this line just throws an exception and you don't handle it in any way. I'd start with adding a try-catch over the code. My guess is that your app pool identity could possibly have no permissions to alter the database structure (and this is what the migration possibly does).

Comment: You do not need to Migrate after each connection, only when the structure of the c# classes change (not the data).  Migrate usually failing when there are errors in the connection string.   Recently a lot of sites are changing authentication from Windows Authentication to OAUTH 2.0.  So I would check the authentication method of connecting to the database.  If you have another method of connecting to the database I would verify you still can connect to the database.

Comment: @jdweng: the code doesn't seem to migrate *after each connection*, the migration code is executed once, at start.

Comment: @WiktorZychla : The migrate code is in program.cs and is run every time the application starts.  The connection is not completing so the migration is never taking place.

Comment: @jdweng: the migration should run everytime application starts. It just shouldn't run on every client's connection and that's what I understood from your *after each connection*

Comment: @WiktorZychla : Migration should be used rarely on production databases.  It should only run when the structure changes.  Migration is used to update the database to match the c# classes when the class structure changes.  It has nothing to do with the data itself.

Comment: @jdweng: Not sure what you mean by *rarely*, migrations should be applied always when necessary. Running migrations at application start is a common practice. It ensures migrations are checked everytime application starts which could be triggered by publishing a new version. EF handles migrations in an idempotent way, if no migration is necessary, migrations are skipped and not applied. Alternative would be to run migrations "by hand" which can be infeasible under automatic CI/CD pipeline.

Comment: @WiktorZychla : My point is it is not necessary in production, may be during development when the c# classes change.  Since c# classes do not change in a production environment it is not necessary to run every time the application is started.

Comment: @jdweng: it could be not necessary but the whole point of the `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion` migration strategy (and other similar approaches like the one from this query) is to call it always at start to ensure the db is migrated, in case of any change. The `.Migrate()` call is safe, it doesn't do anything if there are no changes. My point, on the other hand, is then you possibly shouldn't point this to the OP as an issue as it's perfectly valid and the point of the question is why it's failing (vs "you shouldn't do it there").

Answer (score 0):

The reason for your problem is that you have made changes to the entities in your application that are incompatible with the data in your database. For example, column C in your table X is already nullable and has null value for some table records. Now suppose that in your changes you require column C to have a value.

The solution is to correct the inconsistent data with your changes and then run the program after which the migration takes place.

If you have a lot of changes and your database is a test, you can completely delete the database to build it from scratch.